# Download in angular 8 a txt

Tags: html, angular, save-as

Good, I wanted to have a button on the page that when I pressed it would download a file in txt that I have saved, I have found the function saveAs but it gives me errors, is there another way to make it easier?
Code:

```
uploader: FileUploader;
    download(){
       saveAs(this.uploader, 'data.txt');
     }
```

HTML:

```
<button (click)="download()" class="btn"><i (click)="download()" class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
```

The error that gives me with the saveAs:

> TextAnomComponent.html:42 ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute
>   'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the
>   signature provided.

Comment: Where's the code for saveAs?

Comment: It is a bookstore import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

Comment: `TextAnomComponent.html:42` would be very helpful if you point us the line 42 of this file.

Comment: Is the button <button (click)="download()" class="btn"><i (click)="download()" class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that `this.uploader` is blob type.

If everything is right, then you to check `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` existing on your browser or not

if not then create a link to do download.

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(this.uploader, "data.txt");
}else {
  const downloadLink = window.document.createElement('a');

  // get the this.uploader file type and put in type below
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([this.uploader], { type: ... }));

  downloadLink.download = "data.txt";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: The uploader I have of type FileUploader, how do I pass it to blob?

Comment: Dont need to do anything. The file itself is blob type already. If you get in from input file. you have to get it from `.files` property. If you get it from http response. Then u need to define the `Content-Type`.